# Javascript global variable not work when use phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I created accelerator android application using phonegap.In application show the accelerator
value and save that value to csv file

But in csv file get null value. follow i show link that i use to create this application.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

In my code 'mycsv' variable didn't get value in 'gotFileWriter' function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
    var watchID = null;

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        startWatch();
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    // Start watching the acceleration
    //
    function startWatch() {

        // Update acceleration every 1 milli seconds
        var options = { frequency: 1 };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);

    }

    // Stop watching the acceleration
    //
    function stopWatch() {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
     var mycsv;

    function onSuccess(acceleration) {

        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById('accelerometer').innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' + 
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />'+


                            'Hour: ' + d.getHours() + '<br />' + 
                            'Minit: ' + d.getMinutes() + '<br />' + 
                            'second: ' + d.getSeconds() + '<br />' + 
                            'millisecond: ' + d.getMilliseconds() + '<br />' 



                            ;

     var str2 = d.getFullYear().toString();
     var str1 = ",";

       mycsv= str2.concat(str1,d.getMonth().toString(),str1,d.getDate().toString(),str1,d.getHours().toString(),str1,d.getMinutes().toString(),str1,d.getSeconds().toString(),str1,d.getMilliseconds().toString());

        document.getElementById('csvitem').innerHTML = mycsv;




    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    // csv file create and save /////////////////////////

     function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("kinectAcceler.csv", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
          writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log('finished writing');
                if (callback !== undefined) {
                    callback(writer);
                }
            };
            writer.write(window.mycsv);


    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }





    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
    <button onclick="stopWatch();">Stop Watching</button>
    <p id="csvitem">..<p>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better to use one of 2 cordova libraries.

Comment: i edit that,it printing mistake

Comment: can you console.log / alert out mycsv after you construct the string? What does it show before you try to write it to dom?

Comment: also, I suspect that mycsv is still null by the time you are trying to write it. Pepper your code to see what order your events are firing. If mycsv hasn't been built by the time you try to write it, this would be an expected symptom.

Comment: when i use alert mycsv after i construct the string in onSuccess function.it work it get value. but when write that value it get null.

Comment: @islanddave thank you for comment.i think also that 'mycsv' hasn't been built by the time you try to write it. how can i solve it?